# Pulling in data from an paginated API in to Power BI

Tags: api, pagination, powerbi

i'm trying to pull in this data from Sendcloud but I only get the first 100 rows. Because it is paginated. But before i convert the data to tables it shows me the next link and the previous except on the first one as you can see on the images. Does anyone know how to make a loop for this so can pull in all the data and analyse it?

[image]

[image]

Pull in data to Power BI from a paginated API, want to get all the data instead of the first 100 rows